# Check if two classes are equal (identity)

Tags: c++

I have looked at multiple SO questions and forum posts regarding this, but all posts have either related to pointers (not class instances) or checking equivalence (not identity). Right now I'm using the `==` operator on `this` and the variable containing the other class object. It works, but Eclipse is spitting out a warning `no match for operator==(operand types are Class* and Class` Here are the relevant files:

#### Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Class.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Class a;
    Class b;
    cout << "Are a & b the same instance? " << a.sameInstance(b) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

#### Class.h

```
#pragma once

class Class {
public:
    Class();

    bool sameInstance(Class);
};
```

#### Class.cpp

```
#include "Class.h"

Class::Class() {

}

bool Class::sameInstance(Class c) {
    return this == c;
}
```

Edit: I converted to Class pointers:

## Updated Class.h

```
#pragma once

class Class {
public:
    Class();

    bool sameInstance(Class*);
};
```

## Updated Class.cpp

```
#include "Class.h"

Class::Class() {

}

bool Class::sameInstance(Class* c) {
    return this == c;
}
```

But I'm not sure how to pass b as a pointer in Main.cpp. Left unchanged, it's giving me the error `Invalid arguments Candidates are  bool sameInstance(Class*)`

Edit2: I put an & before a variable name to convert it to a pointer. So instead of `a.sameInstance(b)`, it'd be `a.sameInstance(&b)`.

Comment: Please show your (failed) attempt in a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and also include a copy-paste of the actual error output (in full, complete and unedited).

Comment: Hint: what is the type of `this` and what is the type of `targetPeg`?

Comment: You need to add the equality member function in your class.  The function is actually named operator==.

Comment: `but all posts have either related to pointers (not class instances) or checking equivalence (not identity).` Thats because identity __only__ works for pointers. For non-pointers, `a` can __never__ be `b` (as in identity).

Comment: Like @tkausl said, in C++ an object's pointer *is* its identity.  Comparing pointers is how you compare identity.

Comment: In addition to what @tkausl says, note that taking a parameter *by value* will make another copy, which will *never* be the same identity as anything else.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Fixed

Comment: @RyanBemrose My question was how to check if two class (instances) were equal. The edits are the results of trial and error in an attempt to solve the original question, which never changed. If you have a different way of solving the original problem than what I've been trying, that's still an acceptable answer as it solves the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `sameInstance` method, you must pass the parameter either by reference or by pointer.  Passing by value will not work, because the function will be operating on a copy of the object, which is obviously a different instance.

By reference:

```
bool Class::sameInstance(const Class& c) {
    // Take address of c to get a pointer which can be compared to this
    return this == &c;
}

// main()
cout << "Are a & b the same instance? " << a.sameInstance(b) << endl;
```

By pointer:

```
bool Class::sameInstance(const Class* p) {
    // p is already a pointer which can be compared to this
    return this == p;
}

// main()
// Take the address of b to pass to sameInstance()
cout << "Are a & b the same instance? " << a.sameInstance(&b) << endl;
```

Passing by reference is better idiomatic C++.

In both cases, you should use `const`, because `sameInstance()` doesn't modify its parameter.